# Android SDK is installed on different partition that Intellij can't find

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have installed the Android SDK on different partition that Intellij can't find it while importing a project. It keeps looking in the local C: drive on windows while the SDK has been installed on different partition. I also added the correct path in the project structure. But it's still looking in the C: Drive.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is local.properties file beside your project
you can set the SDK path there manually like this :
sdk.dir=C:\Android\sdk

also you can press F4 on your project root in project structure windows in left side and set SDK there

[image]

Comment: Hi Sadegh, Explain to me the second method please. I am using Intellij IDEA. I didn't know where to press F4 I pressed everywhere but nothing is hapining? the first method worked though. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Sadegh. Works just fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can set SDK location: File - Project Structure - SDK Location